# formatted output: columns

Tags: c++, fstream, formatted

I am desperately trying to produce formatted output by using fstream: columns.

There are two functions (whatever functions Func1, Func2) which produce output (write to the same file, "example.dat"):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout;    
    fout.open("example.dat");

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        fout << Func1(i) << std::endl;
    };

    // Func2 depends on Func1, thus them **cannot** be written at the same time: 
    // fout << Func1() << " " << Func2() << std::endl;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        fout << Func2(i) << std::endl;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

The output will similar to:

Func1(0)

Func1(1)

.

.
.

Func1(9)

Func2(0)

Func2(1)

.

.

.

Func2(9)

My question is: How to produce this output as two columns:

Func1(0)  Func2(0)

Func1(1)  Func2(1)

.

.

.

While them are not simultaneously written.

I suspect that I need to use seekp(), tellp(),  but unfortunately I am not a big expert in this.

Please help!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you just buffer the output of Func1 and Func2 into 2 `vector<string>` so that you can output the results columnated in one loop?

Comment: You should edit your question to remove the (C++) from the title. You don't need to put that in if you have the c++ tag.

Comment: What is the type of `Func1` and `Func2` returned values ? Do they print as fixed size strings ?

Comment: @Nicolas Repiquet: double type function

Comment: Does `Func1` store some data, and `Func2` make use of it? And `Func2` can't be called until all `Func1`s have been called? Can you retrieve all the results of `Func1` later?

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<ostringstream> streams(10);

for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    streams[i] << Func1(i);
}

for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    streams[i] << " " << Func2(i);
}

ofstream fout("example.dat");

for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    fout << streams[i].str() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! But, is it able to store in the vector up to ~ 600 MB ?

Comment: I have 100 "for" loops, each loops produces ~6-7MB of .dat file. So, in order to use your solution, I have to store 100X(6-7MB) of information.Is it possible for "vector"?

Comment: You mean you have 100 columns? Maybe intermediate files are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need seekp and tellp (and writing to the middle of a file is full of pitfalls for the unwary in any case)

Use a std::vector (syntax is probably wrong), thus:

```
std::vector<std::string> res1;
std::vector<std::string> res2;
res1.reserve(10);
res2.reserve(10);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << func1(i);
    res1[i] = s.str();
}
//same for res2, func2
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{

    cout << res1[i] << " " << res2[i] << "\n";
}
```

That's probably the wrong formatting and bits will need tuning. And std::list might work better.

Comment: Thank you Benj and Tom Tanner,  the code abvoe is only prototype of my original code. Actually, I have around 100 columns, each of length ~50^4. Keeping all of them in memory will probably kill it. Thus I am interested to write it into my .dat file, release the memory and run again (next portion of data).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really cannot keep them in memory, you could write to two files, seek back to the start, read them back in line by line and output to your final file to create your concatenated columns.

Something like this might work (I've not tested it):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::fstream  fs_func1;
    std::fstream  fs_func2;
    std::ofstream fout;

    fs_func1.open("func1.dat")
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        fs_func1 << Func1(i) << std::endl;
    }
    fs_func1.seekg(0); // Set get pointer to start of file

    fs_func2.open("func2.dat");
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        fs_func2 << Func2(i) << std::endl;
    };
    fs_func2.seekg(0); // Set get pointer to start of file

    fout.open("example.dat");
    while (!fs_func1.eof() && !fs_func2.eof())
    {
        std::string func1_line;
        std::string func2_line;

        std::getline(fs_func1, func1_line);
        std::getline(fs_func2, func2_line);

        fout << func1_line << " " << func2_line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is probably a Unix command line tool that would do this for you in one step.

Comment: Thanks tinman! But in my case, the concatenated columns should appear incrementally. Since I work with huge data files, reading and writing will be time consuming. Thus, I need to keep (open?) the main file "example.dat" and to add a new column each time after each run. You gave a very nice solution, but how to change to to incremental one?

Comment: @Pomeron: I don't think you can easily change my code to an incremental one unless you can break the for loops into smaller sections, e.g. call Func1() for 0...9 then Func2() for 0...9 then Func1() for 10...19 etc. Well, you could change it, but it would be something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but the idea is to treat your file as a grid.

```
const int COLUMN_COUNT = 2;
const int COLUMN_WIDTH = 8;
const int ROW_WIDTH = COLUMN_COUNT * COLUMN_WIDTH + 1; // + 1 is for endl

void write_cell(std::ostream& out, int row, int column, double value) {

  // how many rows is there in the file ?
  out.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
  int row_count = out.tellp() / ROW_WIDTH;

  // Do we need to create more rows ?
  for(int i = row_count; i <= row; i++) {
    out.seekp(ROW_WIDTH - 1, std::ios_base::cur);
    out << endl;
  }

  // compute cell position
  int pos = row * ROW_WIDTH + column * COLUMN_WIDTH;

  // move to cell position
  out.seekp(pos);

  // write the cell content
  out << std::setw(COLUMN_WIDTH) << value;
}

int main()
{
  std::ofstream fout;    
  fout.open("example.dat");

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    write_cell(fout, i, 0, Func1(i));
  };

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    write_cell(fout, i, 1, Func2(i));
  };

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)  
{  
    fout << Func1(i);  
};  
fout<<endl;  

for (int i=0;i<10;i++)  
{  
    fout << Func2(i);  
};  
fout<<endl;
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but that would produce the output in two rows, not two columns. If you change your answer to show how to transpose that into two columns it would probably be quite a good answer.